# Oracle VirtualBox Ubuntu 22.04 terminal not opening

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, 22.04, oracle

I did a fresh install on oracle virtual box of Ubuntu 22.04 twice no luck opening the terminal. It is only loading then nothing pops up.

I tried many google searches with no luck. I used the ISO ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64

I also tried an older version Ubuntu 20.04.5 and still exactly the same problem.

Comment: Details are needed. I installed 22.04 a few times. Maybe switch to X11 will help.

Comment: I think it's well detailed, The terminal doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04 or 20.05 on an Oracle Virtual Box. and I don't know what's X11 means tbh.

Comment: It works for me. So it can't be reproduced ;-)

Comment: I don't understand you, if you can help  me I'll be grateful.

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem. I can open terminal and I don't know what kind of a problem you have.

Comment: when I click on Terminal .. it loads in the top bar for some time and then disappear and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64 won't properly install and run on VM Box 7.x, version 6.x works well. The problem is not only about terminal but running almost everything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Install the virtual system without unattended installation. Check ***Skip unattended installation***.

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you don't want (or don't have time) to break your head on this, you can try these two solutions that worked for me:

- open "Ubuntu Software" and look for an alternative terminal (I suggest 'Xfce terminal')
- install a version of VB lower than 7.x

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with running Ubuntu as VM in virtualbox. For some bizarre reason, this resolved the issue.

*Go to settings -> Language&Settings -> Change English (United States) to English (Canada) then restart*

Now you should be able to access terminal.